# How to color the Python syntax in nano

Tags: macos, python

I have been using nano a lot recently to code on Python. I have been flying by on it all until this little stump, no color... it makes it harder to know if you got the syntax right and harder to code! I'm not the best at code so please be nice and use step by step guide.

Comment: IMO [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) is a much better way to go!

Comment: An IDE or better text editor might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily "update and use color" on OS X using nano, so use an alternative text editor, [Sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) is a good shout.

Answer (score 6):

Nano is perfectly fine as a simple code editor. It has wonderful syntax highlighting. You will probably want an up-to-date version of nano.

1. Install homebrew: https://brew.sh/
2. Install nano: `brew install nano`
3. Add this line to `~/.nanorc`. That directory has all the syntax highlighting definition files.

   ```
   include "/usr/local/share/nano/*.nanorc"
   ```

Comment: what if I don't have the folder /usr/local/share/nano/

Comment: If you install using homebrew, it should create /usr/local/share/nano as a symlink to `/usr/local/Cellar/nano/#.#/share` where `#.#` is the version number.  If you have multiple users, you can also create the file `/usr/local/etc/nanorc` and add the include line to that.  Then everyone on the system should be able to have colorful nano.  If you installed on homebrew and that directory does NOT exist, you may have installed using a _cask_, which is not the same program at all.  See https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/nano vs https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nano

Comment: Does anyone know why even this fails to colour `nano ~/.bash_profile`? It's always nice on ubuntu to `nano ~/.bashrc` and get colours.

Comment: @Pi Add a "shebang" at the top of your `~/.bash_profile`, such as `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. That will help `nano` and other editors figure out that it's a bash script.

Comment: @Pi Or you can edit `/usr/local/share/nano/sh.nanorc` to add `"\.bash_profile$"` to the `syntax` line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the default version of nano included with OS X is very basic; it may not support syntax highlighting.

(source: https://gist.github.com/BlakeGardner/5587269)

You could try installing an updated version of nano using homebrew and then find instructions for enabling colors.

See also this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642617/nano-syntax-highlighting-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion) regarding installing updated nano.

Alternatively, you could also try a different editor such as TextMate, Emacs, or Vim. These editors will have additional convenience features like auto indentation.

Comment: I went and used macports to install one, ill try to use homebrew or git.

Comment: and good job sighting your sources

Comment: THis is for c, i need python

Comment: After updating to a newer nano, in `/usr/local/share/nano/`, you'll have various `*.nanorc` files. All you have to do is have a `~/.nanorc` file with `include /usr/local/share/nano/python.nanorc`